# Instantiate a Scala case class parameters using some of its own parameters

Tags: scala

I want to set the default value of a parameter of a case class using its own parameters that were declared previously. Something like:

```
case class TestClass(param1 : String, param2 : String = s"The value of param1 is : $param1")
```

This, however, throws an error stating the variables are not defined.  Can anyone suggest how I can accomplish this or any alternate ways forward?

Comment: `param2` should be a method or public variable inside `case class TestClass(param1: String) {val param2 = ... } `

Answer (score 3):

You can provide an additional `apply` method in the companion object that computes some parameters of the `case class`:

```
case class TestClass(param1 : String, param2 : String)

object TestClass {
  def apply(param1: String): TestClass = 
    TestClass(param1, s"The value of param1 is : $param1")
}
```

You can use either `apply` method:

```
scala> TestClass("foo")
res0: TestClass = TestClass(foo,The value of param1 is : foo)

scala> TestClass("foo", "bar")
res1: TestClass = TestClass(foo,bar)
```

---

Note, that while it's possible to move `param2` to a second parameter list or inside the class definition:

```
case class TestClass(param1: String)(param2: String = s"The value of param1 is : $param1")

// Here it's also harder to override the value of `param2`, if needed.
case class TestClass(param1: String) {
  val param2: String = s"The value of param1 is : $param1"
}
```

this changes the semantics of the generated `unapply`, `equals`, `hashCode` and most importantly `copy` methods, so in many cases this is not a viable solution.